# Hadoop/Python: Loading a reference file to use in the mapper

Tags: python, hadoop

I want to process CSV files in Python with Hadoop, but I need to reference another file that contains lookup information.

I read that I can use the -files command line option which creates a symlink to the local file, but how do I reference this file in my Python mapper file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once this job was created in Amazon EMR, I could copy the file to S3 and reference it directly using the `-cacheFile` option:

```
bin/hadoop ... -cacheFile s3://my-bucket/files/cachefile.csv#reference
```

In Python I could then open this file:

```
with open("reference") as reference_file:
    references = reference_file.read().splitlines()
```